# How to save additional user data to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am successful in saving the additional `firstName`, `lastName`, `email` and `gender` into a collection on Cloud Firestore.

I now want to be able to use and change this data in the settings screen of my app. Eg: if the user wants to change email. The issue is that the email is saved in Firebase Auth but is also saved in the `profiles` collection in Cloud Firestore. Can you change both at the same time?

Here is my SessionStore:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
  @Published var profile: UserProfile?
  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
  @Published var session: User? {didSet{self.didChange.send(self) }}
  var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
  func listen() {
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
      if let user = user {
        self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
      }
      else {
        self.session = nil
      }
    })    
  }
    
  private var profileRepository = UserProfileRepository()
   
  func signUp(email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, gender: 
    String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error signing up: \(error)")
        completion(nil, error)
        return
      }
            
      guard let user = result?.user else { return }
      print("User \(user.uid) signed up.")
            
      let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: user.uid, 
                                    email: user.email ?? "", 
                                    firstName: firstName, 
                                    lastName: lastName, 
                                    gender: gender)
      self.profileRepository.createProfile(profile: userProfile) { (profile, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
          completion(nil, error)
          return
        }
        self.profile = profile
        completion(profile, nil)
      }
    }
  }
    
  func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, 
    _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error signing in: \(error)")
        completion(nil, error)
        return
      }
            
      guard let user = result?.user else { return }
      print("User \(user.uid) signed in.")
            
      self.profileRepository.fetchProfile(userId: user.uid) { (profile, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
          completion(nil, error)
          return
        }
                
        self.profile = profile
        completion(profile, nil)
      }
    }
  }
    
  func signOut() {
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
      self.session = nil
      self.profile = nil
    }
    catch let signOutError as NSError {
      print("Error signing out: \(signOutError)")
    }
  }
    
  func unbind() {
    if let handle = handle {
      Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
  }
    
  deinit {
    unbind()
  }
    
  struct User {
    var uid: String
    var email: String?
        
    init(uid: String, email: String?) {
      self.uid = uid
      self.email = email
    }
  }
}
```

My profile repository:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserProfile: Codable {
  var uid: String
  var email: String
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var gender: String
}

class UserProfileRepository: ObservableObject {
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
  func createProfile(profile: UserProfile, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ 
    error: Error?) -> Void) {
    do {
      let _ = try db.collection("profiles").document(profile.uid).setData(from: profile)
      completion(profile, nil)
    }
    catch let error {
      print("Error writing to Firestore: \(error)")
      completion(nil, error)
    }
  }
    
  func fetchProfile(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: 
    Error?) -> Void) {
    db.collection("profiles").document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
      let profile = try? snapshot?.data(as: UserProfile.self)
      completion(profile, error)
    }
  }
}
```

and Settings View:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

struct SettingsView: View {    
  @State var showEdit = false
  var genderOptions = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
  @StateObject var viewModel = UserProfileRepository()
  @State var firstName: String = ""
  @State var lastNameName: String = ""
  @State var email: String = ""
  @State var gender: String = ""
    
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Text("Settings")
        }
        .padding()
                
        VStack {
          Spacer()
          HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
            if showEdit == true {
              TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
                .autocapitalization(.words)
                .keyboardType(.default)
                .font(.subheadline)
            } 
            else {
              Text("")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                  showEdit = true
                }
              }
            }
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "envelope.fill")
              if showEdit == true {
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                  .autocapitalization(.none)
                  .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                  .font(.subheadline)
              } 
              else {
                Text("")
                  .font(.subheadline)
                  .padding()
                  .onTapGesture {
                    showEdit = true
                  }
              }
              HStack {
                Image(systemName: "figure.wave")
                if showEdit == true {
                  Picker(selection: $gender, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(genderOptions, id: \.self) {
                      Text($0)
                        .font(.footnote)
                    }
                  }
                  .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                  .padding()
                }
                else {
                  Text("")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                      showEdit = true
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
              }
            }
            if showEdit == true {
              Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .onTapGesture{
                  showEdit.toggle()
                }
            }  
          }
          .onAppear {
          }
    }
  }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    SettingsView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question or problem here? Can you clarify what that is so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple of notes:

1. No need to implement `didChange = PassthroughSubject` on your `SessionStore` - as soon as you change any of the `@Published` properties, any subscribers will be notified.
2. No need to implement your own `User` struct - just use the one you get from Firebase Auth - it has all the attributes you care for.
3. In the *Settings* view, try wrapping the entire view in a `NavigationView`, setting the `navigationBarTitle` to `Settings` - that should give you the typical settings UI. See [this implementation](https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/blob/master/final/MakeItSo/MakeItSo/Views/SettingsView.swift) for reference.

As for your question: if you want to update the user's data in Firebase Auth, you need to use Firebase Auth's features to do so:

1. To update their basic profile info ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile))

- use `createProfileChangeRequest()`
- set the new values on the request object
- call `changeRequest?.commitChanges` to perform the changes

2. To update their email ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address))

- use `updateEmail(to: email)`

Once those calls finish successfully (use the respective callbacks, *keeping in mind these are asynchronous operations*), you can update the user's info in your `profiles` collection in Firestore.